# why does windows xp forget my taskbar height between logons?

Tags: windows-xp, taskbar

Every time I log on, I unlock my taskbar, double its height, then lock it again.

Next time I log back on, it's back to single height again.

Can anyone tell me what would cause this?

Thanks

Tim

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem. The only way I have been able to solve it was through right clicking on Start, selecting properties and making the changes there. For some reason, simply unlocking the task bar by right clicking on it often doesn't work for me.

Comment: This isn't quite what I meant.  I can always unlock the taskbar by right clicking on it - I don't have to go into properties.  My problem was that XP doesn't remember the change *across login sessions*. Having said that, I did try locking/unlocking via properties as you suggested, but it didn't have any effect on my issue. Next time I logged in, the taskbar was back to the default height again.

Comment: is your profile corrupt? that might be your problem, look in the system log to see if you have profile errors.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to restore the taskbar to its defualt functionality. Visit the following URL http://www.kellys-korner-xp.com/xp_tweaks.htm

and look for the link "Restore Taskbar to Default Functionality". It is option #164. By clicking on the link , you will be executing a .vbs (script) file, or at least downloading it and then executing it. -Sobhi

Answer (score 0):

It is because of improper registry. Use Tuneup utilities to cleanup registries and restore your default taskbar